# https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth? Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: authentication, redirect, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am trying to authenticate with a Google api but keep getting **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**
I have set up my redirect URL in the google console https://console.developers.google.com/project but it keeps saying **The redirect URL in the request: http:/localhost:6804/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URL.**

I have set my URL to may different URLs but it keeps sugesting **http:/localhost:6804/authorize/** is wrong not matter what URL i have inserted.

I have also tried setting my redirect URL to http:/localhost:6804/authorize/ but continue to get the error message.

I update my client_secrets.json every time i make a change and have tired waiting for changes to set in.

Here is the error message i recive:

> Request Details
>
> scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload
>
> response_type=code redirect_uri=http:/localhost:6804/authorize/
>
> access_type=offline pageId=none
>
> client_id=789526175471-mh3o48ooi8va0mr0lke62pvqnf3kd2fj.apps.googleusercontent.com
>
> That’s all we know.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is just a typo and it may not be the cause of your problem, but there should be two slashes (`//`) following `http:` in your URL:

```
http://localhost:6804/authorize/
```

instead of

```
http:/localhost:6804/authorize/
```

Also in the above screenshot from the Google console I don't see this URL registered as a redirect URI. I assume it is just one of the tests you did, right?